# Eclipse Action with '@' symbol in the text

Tags: eclipse-plugin, escaping, swt, special-characters, jface

I'm trying to make an Action in eclipse with the '@' symbol in the text.  But when the menu renders the @ is missing, and instead there is a huge gap where the '@' should be.

Does the '@' symbol have a special meaning in Eclipse/JFace/SWT? Can I somehow escape it?  Using @@, causes the '@' to be shown but the huge space is still there.

Comment: Have you tried using "\u0040" instead?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was found in the comments of setText in the Action class:

```
    /**
 * Sets the text for this action.
 * <p>
 * Fires a property change event for the <code>TEXT</code> property if the
 * text actually changes as a consequence.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The accelerator is identified by the last index of a tab character. If
 * there are no tab characters, then it is identified by the last index of a
 * '@' character. If neither, then there is no accelerator text. Note that
 * if you want to insert a '@' character into the text (but no accelerator,
 * you can simply insert a '@' or a tab at the end of the text.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @param text
 *            the text, or <code>null</code> if none
 */
```